# Pyspark AND/ALSO Partition Column Query

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How do you perform a AND/ALSO query in pyspark? I want both conditions to be met for results to be filtered.

Original dataframe:

```py
df.count()
4105
```

The first condition does not find any records:

```py
df.filter((df.created_date != 'add')).count()
4105
```

Therefore I would expect the AND clause here to return `4105`, but instead it continues to filter on `df.lastUpdatedDate`:

```py
df.filter((df.created_date != 'add') & (df.lastUpdatedDate != '2022-12-21')).count()
3861
```

To me `3861` is the result of an OR clause. How do I address this? `lastUpdatedDate` is a partition filter based on .explain() so maybe that has something to do with these results?

> ...PartitionFilters: [isnotnull(lastUpdatedDate#26), NOT
> (lastUpdatedDate#26 = 2022-12-21)], PushedFilters:
> [IsNotNull(created_date), Not(EqualTo(created_date,add))], ReadSchema ...

Comment: Have you tried using col or chaining both filters?

Comment: I have tried F.col with the same result. I have not chained since to me that would the same thing as it producing now which is filter by one and then filter by a second column. Which I do not want

Comment: Looks like your first condition is true for all and the second condition has some negations, in that case, the results look good i.e. first statement is true for all so it only depends on the second. The first condition effectively has no impact, even removing it will produce the same result.

Comment: In case of OR you would get 4105, as first statement will be true for all - so it doesn't need to check the second one.

Comment: I do not get it: why do you expect 4105 rows by the AND clause? Given that the `df.created_date != 'add'` do not delete any rows, it means that it is always true, so it has no effect in the AND clause. You are getting 3861 rows by the AND clause because they are the rows with `lastUpdatedDate != '2022-12-21'`. Does it make sense?

Comment: Agreed with @PieCot here

Comment: It sounds like I have been in programming conditions too much. The logic I desire is "if statement1 is True and also statement2 is True then filter, else return row".

 The logic I see being performed is "if statement1 is True OR statement2 is True then filter, else return row"

Comment: @vfrank66 Filter is like where clause - i.e. it retains rows that matches the criteria, deleting where there is no match. I.e. True => Keep, False=> Filter out

Comment: To summarize what is the solution to my query?

Comment: @vfrank66 negate the expression basically

Comment: @vfrank66 Added my answer

Answer (score 0):

Going by our conversation in the comments - Your requirement is to filter out rows where (df.created_date != 'add') & (df.lastUpdatedDate != '2022-12-21')

Your confusion seems on the name of the method i.e. filter but rather consider it as where

Where or Filter by definition works the same as SQL where clause i.e. retains the rows where the expression returns true - and drops the rest.

i.e. Consider a dataframe

```
+---+-----+-------+
| id| Name|Subject|
+---+-----+-------+
|  1|  Sam|History|
|  2|  Amy|History|
|  3|Harry|  Maths|
|  4| Jake|Physics|
+---+-----+-------+
```

The below filter would return a new Dataframe with only rows where the Subject is history, i.e. where the expression returned true (i.e. Filters out where it is **false**)

```
rightDF.filter(rightDF.col("Subject").equalTo("History")).show();
```

OR

```
rightDF.where(rightDF.col("Subject").equalTo("History")).show();
```

Output:

```
+---+----+-------+
| id|Name|Subject|
+---+----+-------+
|  1| Sam|History|
|  2| Amy|History|
+---+----+-------+
```

So in your case, you would want to negate the statements to get the results you desire.

i.e. Use equal to instead of not equal to

```
df.filter((df.created_date == 'add') & (df.lastUpdatedDate == '2022-12-21')).count()
```

This means keep rows where **both** statements are True and filter out where any of them is false

Let me know if this works or anything else